# Missing methods using org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
 org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/List;)V
```

Got this error while building a DataSource:

```
return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setName("table_name")
                .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
                .addScript("classpath:sql_schema_path")
                .setDataSourceFactory(embeddedDataSourceFactory) // @bean to pass Factory values
                .build();
```

I guess this `MultiValuedMap.addAll` is used behind the scenes when springframework is trying to build build `EmbeddedDatabase`. Not sure why I get this error tho, any suggestions?

Comment: The error would suggest that you are combining Spring dependencies of different versions. Make sure your dependencies are consistent.

Comment: Please don't add things liked 'solved' to a title. If you managed to solve your problem, accept the answer that helped you solve the problem, or post your own answer and accept it after the timeout.

Comment: I added 'solved' in mind that if someone has familiar problem and when github recommends familiar issues that already exists they could see that its solved, but I'll accept my answer in few days (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so in my case I am using `<springversion>4.2.5.RELEASE</springversion>` and in the maven repository it clearly says if I use `spring-boot-jdbc-2.1.5` I need to use atleast  springframework version 5.1.7.RELEASE [mvn_link_here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.1.5.RELEASE). I might have missed it, my bad.

If someone uses spring only, so you should use `SimpleDriverDataSource` which is part of `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource` and using it you can specify url, driver, username and the password.

There's not much examples out there, so the way I achieved it and it works is like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:properties.file")
public class DatabaseServiceImplTestConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSourceFactory embeddedDataSourceFactory() {
        return new DataSourceFactory() {
            @Override
            public ConnectionProperties getConnectionProperties() {
                return new ConnectionProperties() {

                    @Override
                    public void setUsername(String username) {}

                    @Override
                    public void setPassword(String password) {}

                    @Override
                    public void setUrl(String url) {}

                    @Override
                    public void setDriverClass(Class<? extends Driver> driverClass) {}

                };
            }

            @Override
            public DataSource getDataSource() {
                SimpleDriverDataSource sds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
                sds.setDriverClass(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class); // <- try to return Driver object too (using setDriver)
                sds.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.connection.url"));
                sds.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.connection.username"));
                sds.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.connection.password"));
                return sds;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource embeddedDataSource(DataSourceFactory embeddedDataSourceFactory) {

        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setName("table_name_here")
                .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
                .addScript("classpath:path/to/your/shema.sql")
                .setDataSourceFactory(embeddedDataSourceFactory)  // <- call the bean here
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, then you shouldn't even specify the version of any Spring dependency, but rely on the Spring Boot BOM to determine versions for you.